# Rate of eigenvalue decay for Erdős–Rényi random graph

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, random-graphs, random-matrices

How fast do eigenvalues decay in a large Bernoulli  [random](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BernoulliGraphDistribution.html#:%7E:text=The%20Bernoulli%20graph%20is%20constructed,whether%20to%20generate%20directed%20edges)  graph for a fixed large $n$ (number of nodes) and fixed $p$ (probability of dropping an edge)? Also known as Erdős–Rényi random graph. Empirically, if we sort eigenvalue in decreasing order, their magnitudes seem to decay exponentially with $i$=position in the sorted list. Can someone point me to a reference or a way to justify this?

[image]

This graph plots log of absolute value of eigenvalues of a large Erdős–Rényi random graph, arranged in decreasing order.

`ListLogPlot@Rest@Reverse@Sort@Abs@Eigenvalues@N@AdjacencyMatrix@RandomGraph@BernoulliGraphDistribution[2000, 0.5]`

**Edit** eigenvalues follow the shape of semicircle CDF
[image]

[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-bernoulli-graphs.nb)

Comment: "sometimes called binomial random graph" ...and much more commonly called an [Erdős–Rényi random graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model).

Comment: For constant average degree? Or for which dependence on $n$?

Comment: @md5 I'm interested in the rate of decay of $i$th largest eigenvalue as $i$ increases, for given $n$ and average degree $p$. An exponential or super-exponential upper bound would be pretty useful. The shape in the graph looks pretty similar for a range of $n$ and $p$

Comment: Are you sure your graph doesn't show a result for $n=2000$?

Comment: Usually $p$ denotes the probability to select an edge, so I guess you mean that $p=d/n$, where $d$ is a constant independent of $n$? One could also look at different regimes of $p$, and the rate of decay of the eigenvalues might be different

Comment: @md5 in my case, d and n are some fixed constants, so the decay is in terms of `i` rather than `n`

Comment: The range of eigenvalues you're interested it is a bit ambiguous to me. I was also further thrown off off by not being well versed with Mathemtica, and assuming the x-axis in your graph was the eigenvalue magnitude -- could you clarify the axis meanings?

Comment: @jwimberley I sort absolute values of eigenvalues in decreasing order. This gives me a list of rapidly decreasing numbers, can you tell me how fast they decrease?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $n \to \infty$ (with constant $p$) the eigenvalues of $G_{n,p}$ are *essentially* described by Wigner's semicircle law.

For this purpose, let $(Y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of random $n \times n$ symmetric matrices, where

- all off-diagonal entries of all matrices follow the same distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$;
- all diagonal entries of all matrices follow the same distribution with mean $0$ and finite variance.

Let $X_n = Y_n/\sqrt n$. As $n \to \infty$, the eigenvalues of $X_n$ converge to a distribution with PDF $f(t) = \frac1{2\pi}\sqrt{4-t^2}$, in the sense that the number of eigenvalues of $X_n$ in the range $[a,b] \subseteq [-2,2]$ converges to $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(t)\,dt$.

---

For $G_{n,p}$, we almost satisfy the hypotheses of the theorem, except that the distribution of the off-diagonal entries is Bernoulli, which does not have mean $0$. This only affects the leading eigenvalue, which is $\approx np$; the other eigenvalues follow a semicircle law.

Here is an example with $n=2000$ and $p = \frac12$, where I plot a histogram of the actual eigenvalues against the theoretical semicircle (centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $\sqrt{2000}$, then normalized to integrate to $2000$). You don't see the leading eigenvalue of $\approx 1000$ here.

[image]

Mathematica code:

```
Show[
   Histogram[Eigenvalues@N@AdjacencyMatrix@
      RandomGraph@BernoulliGraphDistribution[2000, 0.5], {1}], 
   Plot[Sqrt[2000 - x^2]/(1000 Pi)*2000, {x, -45, 45}]]
```

Comment: the tricky thing is to connect semi-circle law to the graph I'm seeing

Comment: The graph you're seeing doesn't have a nice formula, because you have to go from the PDF to the CDF and then invert it.

Comment: ok, I'll tinker with it some more. Basically I'm trying to figure out how fast the eigenvalues in my graph decay. CDF of the semi-circle does not resemble the graph I'm seeing, it's symmetric around y=x line, but graph of eigenvalue magnitude vs position in the list is not

Comment: GraphicsColumn[{Plot[
   CDF[WignerSemicircleDistribution[1], x], {x, -1, 1}], 
  ListPlot@Rest@
    Reverse@Sort@
      Abs@Eigenvalues@
        N@AdjacencyMatrix@
          RandomGraph@BernoulliGraphDistribution[2000, 0.5]
  }]

Comment: When you plot the magnitude of the $i^{\text{th}}$ largest eigenvalue, you are looking at the inverse CDF rather than the CDF. In other words, the $250^{\text{th}}$ eigenvalue out of $2000$ will have magnitude about $a$ if $\int_{|x|>a} f(x)\,dx = \frac{250}{2000}$.

Comment: Ah, I was missing the absolute value on |x|. Indeed this seems like the same distribution

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer currently does not address the underlying question, because it mistook the graph for a histogram and and was answering the unasked question about the distribution of large eigenvalues -- e.g. $p(\lambda)$ for large $\lambda$, and pointing out that in fact $p(\lambda) = 0$ for large enough $\lambda$, much narrower of course than an exponential distribution.

It's a basic fact that the maximum eigenvalue of an adjacency matrix is bounded above by the maximum degree of any vertex in the graph -- are you sure your plot does not show the distribution for $n=2000$? You can find a proof of this on Wikipedia. Here's a simple proof of the weaker property that the eigenvalue's magnitudes are bounded by the number of vertices in the graph. The sum of squared eigenvalues $\sum_i \left| \lambda_i \right|^2$ is the trace of the square of the adjacency matrix $A^2$. For one, this implies a hard upper bound on the magnitude of any eigenvalue. Since the elements of the (symmetric) adjacency matrix are either 0 or 1, an element $(A^2)_{ii}$ on the diagonal of the squared adjacency matrix is
$$
(A^2)_{ii} = \sum_{j} A_{ij} A_{ji} = \sum_{j} A_{ij}^2 = \sum_{j} A_{ij} = d(i).
$$
Since the degree of the $i$-th vertex is absolutely bounded by $n-1$, where $n$ is the number of vertices in the graph, the upper bound on any eigenvalue's magnitude is
$$
\left| \lambda_i \right|^2 \leq \sum_{i} \left| \lambda_i^2 \right| = \mathrm{tr} \left( A^2 \right) = \sum_{i} (A^2)_{ii}\leq n(n-1).
$$

When the edges to the graph are added randomly, the degrees of separate vertices are of course correlated. Assuming as an approximation they are independent, then each vertice's degree is $p(n-1)$ on average and
$$
E \left[ \sum_{i} \left| \lambda_i^2 \right| \right] \approx pn(n-1).
$$

Comment: I dropped the largest eigenvalue from the plot, it seems to be an outlier, probably easier to model it separately from the rest of the spectrum which seems to decay exponentially